# I am working on implementing job queue. Using TPL for the same. Trying to restrict number of jobs at a time using ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads. no luck

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

****To Restrict the thread :****

```
int workerThreads, completionPortThreads;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);
workerThreads = 2;

 ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(workerThreads, completionPortThreads);
```

To run the job I tried 2 options
Option 1.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc),task);
```

Option 2:

```
Task runner = new Task(() => taskProcessor.ImportIntoArt(task),TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning|TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
runner.Start();
```

I expect this code has to pick up first two jobs for processing and 3rd one should go in to the queue. As expected first two jobs will start, however 3rd one will also be picked up for processing.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How many processors do you have? As [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads(v=vs.110).aspx) say, "You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer." and also "In addition, you cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the corresponding minimum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads. To determine the minimum thread pool size, call the GetMinThreads method".

Comment: @stuartd, assuming your guess is correct about the number of processors, this comment is worthy of being an answer.  I'd upvote it.

Comment: is there any other way to do this using TPL?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [QueuedTaskScheduler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/) from [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/) in conjunction with `Task.Factory.StartNew` method:

```
var scheduler = new QueuedTaskScheduler(TaskScheduler.Default, 2);

var jobAction = new Action<string>(
    jobName =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am job " + jobName + " and I start at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("I am job " + jobName + " and I finish at " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    });

var jobs = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 6)
    .Select(num => Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => jobAction("Job" + num),
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
        scheduler))
    .ToList();

Task.WhenAll(jobs).Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to achieve this task using TPL, but as @stuartd has made a comment that we can't do that with threadpool, then you can achieve this task traditional way by creating required number of thread and run them infinitely and observe the collection of a task which of type query.
Please refer below code if you want to achieve the task without using other libraries.

```
//Declare queue of task.
        static Queue<int> taskQueue = new Queue<int>();
        static readonly object lockObj = new object();
        //Get task to perform.
        static int? GetNextTask()
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                if (taskQueue.Count > 0)
                    return taskQueue.Dequeue();
                else return null;
            }
        }
        //Add task to queue from different thread.
        static void AddTask(int task)
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                taskQueue.Enqueue(task);
            }
        }
        static void PerformThreadOperation()
        {
            //Run infinite for current thread.
            while (true)
            {
                var task = GetNextTask();
                //If there is task then perform some action else make thread sleep for some time you can set event to resume thread.
                if (task.HasValue)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task Initiate => {0}", task.Value);
                    Thread.Sleep(4000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Task Complete => {0}", task.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task not found, thread is going to be sleep for some moment.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} enter in sleep mode.", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        }
        //Create required thread to process task parallely.
        static void TestThreadApplication()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PerformThreadOperation));
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(PerformThreadOperation);
            thread.Start();
            thread1.Start();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                taskQueue.Enqueue(i);
            }
            TestThreadApplication();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);

            for (int i = 6; i < 10; i++)
            {
                taskQueue.Enqueue(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```